# Laravel 4 Modal Ajax doesnt work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4

I have code for call other page in Modal Bootstrap using Laravel 4. But in a modal not appear the other page. The below is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        //ambil data untuk detail buku
        $(".detail-dialog").click(function() {

             $('#container-modal-ajax')                              
             .dialog({
                 modal: true, 
                 title: 'Rincian Buku',
                 shadow: true,
                 show:{ effect: "puff", duration: 500 },
                 hide:{ effect: "puff", duration: 1000 },
                 overlay: true,
                 draggable: true,
                 open: function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/user/home"                          
                    });
                },    
                 buttons: [
                    {
                      text: "ok",
                      click: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      }
                    }
                  ]                             
             });

             $("#dialog").load("detail.php", function() {

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Is it true if i write down the controller routes,in url ajax section?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yu are using jQuery for your AJAX call which according to their docs defaults to a GET request.

So you need to make sure you have a route setup for /user/home

An example  route would be:

```
    Route::get('/user/home', function()
{
    return 'User home';
});
```